# Философия ORM'ов

Tags: orm

Начинаю разбираться, что такое ORM и с чем его едят. Если я правильно понял, то основная его идея - это избавить разработчика от прямой работы с SQL. Для этого в языке объявляются сущности БД, скажем, в виде классов. И идет работа с этими сущностями. А сам фреймворк уже дергает соответствующие SQL запросы.

Т.е. в терминах Java, есть некоторый интерфейс-контроллер

```
interface DBController {
  public List<T> select(...);
  public void insert(AEntity);
  public void update(AEntity);
  public void delete(AEntity);
}
```

в который передается наша сущность для обработки. `select` - выбирает какие-то записи к кладет их в список `insert`, `update`, `delete` выполняют манипуляции с сущностями по некоторым правилам.

Если пока все правильно, то вопрос - как должна решаться такая задача

> Есть таблица файлов такой структуры
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE files (
>   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
>   name VARCHAR,
>   data BLOB,
>   last_download TIMESTAMP
> )
> ```
>
> нужно вывести список файлов, при клике на файл его скачать, а потом обновить дату последнего скачивания

Описываю сущность

```
class file {
  public int id,
  public String name,
  public byte[] data,
  public Date last_download
}
```

И сразу вижу проблемы

1. При заполнении списка для вывода на страницу, у меня из базы считаются блобы, которые занимают много места и не нужны для отображения списка
2. После скачивания мне нужно обновить одно поле и не трогать остальные. Т.е. вместо дефолтного запроса

   ```
   UPDATE files SET
     name = :name,
     data = :data,
     last_download = :last_download
   WHERE
     id = :id
   ```

   мне нужно выполнить такой

   ```
   UPDATE files SET
     last_download = :last_download
   WHERE
     id = :id
   ```

Это все элементарно решается? Или мне нужно описывать три сущности

```
class fileInfo {
  public int id,
  public String name,
  public Date last_download
}

class fileDownload {
  public int id,
  public byte[] data
}

class fileUpdate {
  public int id,
  public Date last_download
}
```

Если принципиально, то пусть в качестве ORM будет realm

Comment: дак обычно любой ORM позволяет задавать поля для выборки, а-ля `table->select(['id' ,' name'])`. а при обновлениях ORM должен следить, какие поля были обновлены, и только их писать в update запрос. так что сущность должна быть, конечно, одна

Comment: @teran Т.е. к каждому полю где-то должен прилагаться массив `is_modified`?

Comment: либо так либо хранить исходные значения. последнее более практично, хотя и требует больше памяти, если это важно. либо комбинировать оба способа.